# Is there any plugins for creating company profiles (and show them in posts) in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a technology news blog where I write about tech companies and start-up. I would like to add company profiles to them, and show them in different posts. Is it possible any way?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option would be to setup a [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) called "profiles" (or whatever name suits you) and then use a plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to build your company profile fields (name, address, url, bio etc.)

You can skip the ACF plugin and use [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields), but if you need the data input process to be user/non techy freindly than ACF is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

hi  is a lightweight plugin for adding job-board functionality to your WordPress site
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/

Comment: Does it also adds companies?